# how to add image between two divs under .row (using bootstrap 4)

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

here is my code:

```
<div class="row"style="">
  <div class="panel panel-success col-sm-3" style="background-color: #d16b55; ">
    <div class="panel-body" style="height: 1000px; margin-left: 50px;overflow: hidden !important;">   
      <img class="card-img-top" src="movie_poster/sonic-the-hedgehog.jpg " alt="Card image" style="height:370px;width:100%;margin-top:15px;position: absolute;left: 50px;overflow: visible;">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-success col-sm-9 " style="background-color: #ffe2db;"><div class="panel-body"></div></div>
</div>
```

[image]

Please check this image
I am 100% sure that half the image is hidden behind the second div. I can see it when removing the second div.

Comment: I want to help you but, there's nothing I can do without seeing some code. An image doesn't help anyone. Please either post your code or something like a JSFiddle.

Comment: sorry for that. you can see the code now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**it was a layering issue, it worked fine when placed after two divs**

[check this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ayKAJ.png)

the code:

```
 <div class="row"style="margin-top: 10px;">
      <div class="panel panel-success col-sm-3" style="background-color: #d16b55; ">
        <div class="panel-body" style="height: 1000px; margin-left: 50px;overflow: hidden !important;">   

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="panel panel-success col-sm-9 " style="background-color: #ffe2db;"><div class="panel-body"></div></div>
      <img class="card-img-top col-sm-3" src="movie_poster/sonic-the-hedgehog.jpg " alt="Card image" style="height:370px;width:100%;margin-top:15px;position: absolute;left: 100px;">
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The last image loaded will be "on top" however if your margin values for your divs are positive your content shouldn't overlap.